# MySQL query - possible to include this clause?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following query, which retrieves 4 adverts from certain categories in a random order.

At the moment, if a user has more than 1 advert, then potentially all of those ads might be retrieved - I need to limit it so that only 1 ad per user is displayed.

Is this possible to achieve in the same query?

```
SELECT      a.advert_id, a.title, a.url, a.user_id, 
            FLOOR(1 + RAND() * x.m_id) 'rand_ind' 

FROM        adverts AS a
INNER JOIN  advert_categories AS ac
ON          a.advert_id = ac.advert_id,
(
            SELECT MAX(t.advert_id) - 1 'm_id' 
            FROM adverts t
)           x

WHERE       ac.category_id IN 
(
            SELECT category_id
            FROM website_categories
            WHERE website_id = '8'
)
AND         a.advert_type = 'text'

GROUP BY    a.advert_id
ORDER BY    rand_ind 
LIMIT       4
```

Comment: Doesn't it work by placing `DISTINCT a.user_id` after the `SELECT`?

Comment: I'm not sure that would make any difference? The rows are still distinct - e.g. same user_id but different advert_ids

Comment: If a user has 10 ads and another user 1, is the user with 10 ads expected to show adds at a statistical frequency of 10 times the user with 1? Or is the expected frequency the same, due to only 1 ad at most per user within the LIMIT 4?

Comment: I would agree with your first statement - statistically, a user with more ads might expect his to be shown more often. If it were the latter rule, how might that affect things query-wise?

Comment: For the latter, it would require a different query built in a completely different way, but would involve much the same techniques with row numbering and `order by rand()`

Comment: Depending on your final answer, just doing a random on qualified adverts might still give a poor balance to all possible users.  If one user has 100 ads, and another only 5,  then the pool of ads per user could be unbalanced and flush some people out.  It might be best to prequery distinct users who qualify with random, get your limit of 4 from THAT group, THEN figure which random add should be used.  This way all users are given the same balance regardless of how many ads they have listed.

Comment: @DRapp - I can see the sense in your explanation. I guess a user with more ads shouldn't find themselves unfairly picked on in terms of more impressions. How would you suggest implementing a logic like that? (I have commented your answer below also).

Comment: @BrynJ, check my new post... it should handle all the conditions you are looking for, but also well documented for the logic behind it without any special @vars or temp storage.

Comment: @Elzo Valugi - you're right, it isn't...have removed tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Note: The solution is the last query at the bottom of this answer.

Test Schema and Data

```
create table adverts (
    advert_id int primary key, title varchar(20), url varchar(20), user_id int, advert_type varchar(10))
;
create table advert_categories (
    advert_id int, category_id int, primary key(category_id, advert_id))
;
create table website_categories (
    website_id int, category_id int, primary key(website_id, category_id))
;
insert website_categories values
    (8,1),(8,3),(8,5),
    (1,1),(2,3),(4,5)
;
insert adverts (advert_id, title, user_id) values
    (1, 'StackExchange', 1),
    (2, 'StackOverflow', 1),
    (3, 'SuperUser', 1),
    (4, 'ServerFault', 1),
    (5, 'Programming', 1),
    (6, 'C#', 2),
    (7, 'Java', 2),
    (8, 'Python', 2),
    (9, 'Perl', 2),
   (10, 'Google', 3)
;
update adverts set advert_type = 'text'
;
insert advert_categories values
    (1,1),(1,3),
    (2,3),(2,4),
    (3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),
    (4,1),
    (5,4),
    (6,1),(6,4),
    (7,2),
    (8,1),
    (9,3),
   (10,3),(10,5)
;
```

Data properties

- each website can belong to multiple categories
- for simplicity, all adverts are of type 'text'
- each advert can belong to multiple categories.  If a website has multiple categories that are matched multiple times in advert_categories for the same user_id, this causes the advert_id's to show twice when using a straight join between 3 tables in the next query.

This query joins the 3 tables together (notice that ids 1, 3 and 10 each appear twice)

```
select *
from website_categories wc
inner join advert_categories ac on wc.category_id = ac.category_id
inner join adverts a on a.advert_id = ac.advert_id and  a.advert_type = 'text'
where wc.website_id='8'
order by a.advert_id
```

To make each website show only once, this is the core query to show all eligible ads, each only once

```
        select *
        from adverts a
        where a.advert_type = 'text'
          and exists (
            select *
            from website_categories wc
            inner join advert_categories ac on wc.category_id = ac.category_id
            where wc.website_id='8'
              and a.advert_id = ac.advert_id)
```

The next query retrieves all the advert_id's to be shown

```
select advert_id, user_id
from (
    select
        advert_id, user_id,
        @r := @r + 1 r
    from (select @r:=0) r
    cross join 
    (
        # core query -- vvv
        select a.advert_id, a.user_id
        from adverts a
        where a.advert_type = 'text'
          and exists (
            select *
            from website_categories wc
            inner join advert_categories ac on wc.category_id = ac.category_id
            where wc.website_id='8'
              and a.advert_id = ac.advert_id)
        # core query -- ^^^
        order by rand()
    ) EligibleAdsAndUserIDs
) RowNumbered
group by user_id
order by r
limit 2
```

There are 3 levels to this query

1. aliased `EligibleAdsAndUserIDs`: core query, sorted randomly using `order by rand()`
2. aliased `RowNumbered`: row number added to core query, using MySQL side-effecting @variables
3. the outermost query forces mysql to collect rows `as numbered` randomly in the inner queries, and `group by user_id` causes it to retain only the first row for each user_id. `limit 2` causes the query to stop as soon as two distinct user_id's have been encountered.

This is the final query which takes the advert_id's from the previous query and joins it back to table `adverts` to retrieve the required columns.

1. only once per user_id
2. feature user's with more ads proportionally (statistically) to the number of eligible ads they have

***Note:** Point (2) works because the more ads you have, the more likely you will hit the top placings in the row numbering subquery*

```
select a.advert_id, a.title, a.url, a.user_id
from
(
    select advert_id
    from (
        select
            advert_id, user_id,
            @r := @r + 1 r
        from (select @r:=0) r
        cross join 
        (
            # core query -- vvv
            select a.advert_id, a.user_id
            from adverts a
            where a.advert_type = 'text'
              and exists (
                select *
                from website_categories wc
                inner join advert_categories ac on wc.category_id = ac.category_id
                where wc.website_id='8'
                  and a.advert_id = ac.advert_id)
            # core query -- ^^^
            order by rand()
        ) EligibleAdsAndUserIDs
    ) RowNumbered
    group by user_id
    order by r
    limit 2
) Top2
inner join adverts a on a.advert_id = Top2.advert_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your incredibly detailed reply. When I have the opportunity, I will go through it thoroughly and test. Just one question - can I use my alternative to order by rand() without affecting the results? It's just that ordering by rand() is very inefficient due to the data size.

Comment: Your alternative is also ordering by rand().  Put `EXPLAIN` before your query to see it.  ordering by rand_int requires the inner expression involving `RAND()` to be fully evaluated for each row, therefore the expense is also `every row visited`. This solution collects all the date (`core query`) once, and everything else is working on that `DERIVED` table.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation cyberkiwi - I do know that my previous benchmarking showed my alternative order by was quicker, but I shall benchmark the new query and report findings also. The adverts table is potentially thousands of rows.

Comment: Initial benchmarking appears to be encouraging in terms of speed, although given my current dataset it's a little hard to be conclusive. If it's not too much trouble, could you provide some information on how you might implement a query weighted to random users, rather than random ads?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking through something but don't have MySQL available.. can you try this query to see if it works or crashes...

```
SELECT 
      PreQuery.user_id, 
      (select max( tmp.someRandom ) from PreQuery tmp where tmp.User_ID = PreQuery.User_ID ) MaxRandom
   from 
      ( select adverts.user_id,
               rand() someRandom
           from adverts, advert_categories
           where adverts.advert_id = advert_categories.advert_id ) PreQuery
```

If the "tmp" alias is recognized as a temp buffer of the preliminary query as defined by the OUTER FROM clause, I might have something that will work...  I think the field as a select statement from a queried from WONT work, but if it does, I know I'll have something solid for you.

Comment: Unfortunately the above doesn't run - I think the issue is in the subquery within select, as MySQL reports that PreQuery is undefined. Any other ideas?

Comment: That was what I was afraid of... Thanks for trying... I'll have to think otherwise and hopefully you'll get a solution otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this one might make the head hurt a bit, but lets get the logical thing going...  The inner most "Core Query" is a basis that gets all unique and randomly assigned QUALIFIED Users that have a qualifying ad base on the category chosen, and type = 'text'.  Since the order is random, I don't care what the assigned sequence is, and order by that.  The limit 4 will return the first 4 entries that qualify.  This is regardless of one user having 1 ad vs another having 1000 ads.

Next, join to the advertisements, reversing the table / join qualifications... but by having a WHERE - IN SUB-SELECT, the sub-select will be on each unique USER ID that was qualified by the "CoreQuery" and will ONLY be done 4 times based on ITs inner limit.  So even if 100 users with different advertisements, we get 4 users.

Now, the Join to the CoreQuery is the Advert Table based on the same qualifying user.  Typically this would join ALL records against the core query given they are for the same user in question... This is correct...  HOWEVER, the NEXT WHERE clause is what filters it down to only ONE ad for the given person.

The Sub-Select is making sure its "Advert_ID" matches the one selected in the sub-select.  The sub-select is based ONLY on the current "CoreQuery.user_ID" and gets ALL the qualifying category / ads for the user (wrong... we don't want ALL ads)...  So, by adding an ORDER BY RAND() will randomize only this one person's ads in the result set... then Limiting THAT by 1 will only give ONE of their qualified ads...

So, the CoreQuery restricts down to 4 users.  Then for each qualified user ID, gets only 1 of the qualified ads (by its inner order by RAND() and LIMIT 1 )...

Although I don't have MySQL to try, the queries are COMPLETELY legit and hope it works for you.... man, I love brain teasers like this...

```
SELECT
       ad1.*
   from 
       ( SELECT ad.user_id,
                count(*) as UserAdCount,
                RAND() as ANYRand
             from 
                website_categories wc
                   inner join advert_categories ac
                      ON wc.category_id = ac.category_id
                      inner join adverts ad
                         ON    ac.advert_id = ad.advert_id 
                           AND ad.advert_type = 'text'
             where
                wc.website_id = 8
             GROUP BY 
                1
             order by
                3 
             limit 
                4 ) CoreQuery,
         adverts ad1
     WHERE
             ad1.advert_type = 'text'
         AND CoreQuery.User_ID = ad1.User_ID
         AND ad1.advert_id in 
                ( select 
                          ad2.advert_id
                     FROM 
                          adverts ad2,
                          advert_categories ac2,
                          website_categories wc2
                     WHERE
                            ad2.user_id = CoreQuery.user_id
                        AND ad2.advert_id = ac2.advert_id
                        AND ac2.category_id = wc2.category_id
                        AND wc2.website_id = 8
                     ORDER BY 
                        RAND()
                     LIMIT 
                        1 )
```

Comment: Thank for the detailed reply. Unfortunately, the query still won't run - "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'". I will try see if I can reformulate it in some way.

Answer (score 1):

I like to suggest that you do the random with php. This is way faster than doing it in mySQL.

"However, when the table is large (over about 10,000 rows) this method of selecting a random row becomes increasingly slow with the size of the table and can create a great load on the server. I tested this on a table I was working that contained 2,394,968 rows. It took 717 seconds (12 minutes!) to return a random row."
http://www.greggdev.com/web/articles.php?id=6

Answer (score 0):

```
set @userid = -1;
select
  a.id,
  a.title,
  case when @userid = a.userid then
    0
  else
    1
  end as isfirst,
  (@userid := a.userid)
from
  adverts a
  inner join advertcategories ac on ac.advertid = a.advertid
  inner join categories c on c.categoryid = ac.categoryid
where
  c.website = 8
order by
  a.userid,
  rand()
having
  isfirst = 1
limit 4
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but doesn't seem to work - is it dependent on substituting my rand_ind for for rand() (a method I'm using for performance reasons), or the removal of GROUP BY (which again is a problem, as an ad can appear in several categories but I only want to return it once)? Also, I'm querying via mysql_query, so I'm assuming the 2 calls (one for set, one for actual query) won't be a problem?

Comment: You can do the set in a FROM statement.  `FROM (SELECT @userid := -1) q`.

Answer (score 0):

Add  COUNT(a.user_id) as owned in the main select directive and add HAVING owned < 2 after Group By

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

I think this is the way to do it, if the one user has more than one advert then we will not select it.